# The position of subview was not what I expected

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uidatepicker

I added a date picker as a subview, and what I expected was that when I press "change date" button, the date picker would show at the bottom of view. But the reality was [simulation result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdNsw.png).

```
@IBAction func onUpdateBirthday(sender: UIButton) {
    showChooseBirthday()
}

func showChooseBirthday() {

    view.addSubview(chooseBirthday)

    let bottomConstraint = chooseBirthday.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor)
    let leftConstraint = chooseBirthday.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor)
    let rightConstraint = chooseBirthday.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.rightAnchor)
    let heightContraint = chooseBirthday.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(60)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([bottomConstraint,leftConstraint,rightConstraint,heightContraint])
    view.layoutIfNeeded() // re-layout the view

    self.chooseBirthday.alpha = 0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) {
        self.chooseBirthday.alpha = 1
    }
```

Here is [a part of storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQUSM.png).

Comment: why dont you open pickerview as inputview

Comment: I`m sorry, iam new in swift, do you have any samples?

Comment: check this http://blog.apoorvmote.com/uipickerview-as-inputview-to-uitextfield-in-swift/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by others, you can add the date picker to a UITextField. Here is an example, I hope it helps you. [Result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5jd5.png)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var birthdayTextField: UITextField!
    var birthdayPicker = UIDatePicker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            configureBirthdayPicker()
        }

    func configureBirthdayPicker(){

        birthdayPicker.datePickerMode = .Date
        birthdayPicker.maximumDate = NSDate()
        birthdayPicker.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        birthdayPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor()

        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barTintColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor()
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
        toolBar.translucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker:")
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancelPicker:")

        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

        birthdayTextField.inputView = birthdayPicker
        birthdayTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

    }

    func donePicker(doneclicked:UIButton){
        print("done clicked")
        birthdayTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func cancelPicker(cancelclicked:UIButton){
        print("cancel clicked")
        birthdayTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use textfield instead of button. and set `pickerview` as `inputview` of textfield so it will open `yourdatepicker` instead of `keyboard` when you will ckick on textfield.

there are many tutorial available for that just google it if you don't have much idea about that.

and in your code you should set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`.

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to No in code